# How to allow non-site admin users to manage the choices for a site column of type Choice

Tags: 2013, development, csom, site-column, choice-field

One of the challenges i always face when adding a site column of type Choice, is how i can allow non-site admin users to be able to manage the Choice site column's Choices?

For example let say i create a new site column of type Choice named "Category" with choices such as "HR","IT","Finance". and later on we wanted to add new Category, currently only me as a site admin i can edit the site column and add the new choice. but i want to allow end users to be able to add/edit/remove choices without giving them any permission on the site level... one way i tried before is that I replaced the Choices site columns with lookup columns, but the problem i faced is that the lookup columns can not be used inside the lists' Metadata Navigation Settings , as the Metadata Navigation Settings for a list can only use columns of type Choice or managed metadata as mentioned here:-

[image]

so i need to keep using Choice site columns but at the same time to allow end users to manage their choices. so i find this appraoch but i did not test it :-

1. for each site column of type Choice, to create a custom list for it.
2. Users will be adding items inside the list, and these items will represent the choices for the related site column.
3. then using a timer job or a scheduled console application, i can write some code which will retrieve all the list items and add them as a choices inside the related site column .

so can anyone adivce on these 2 points:-

1. is my above proposed appraoch a valid way to follow?
2. what are the options i can follow to allow non-site admin users to manage the site columns of type Choice ??

Thanks in advance for any help.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should use Managed Metadata fields instead of Choice fields. Then you could set Submission Policy to Open for target term set which would allow end-users to modify possible choices.

If you don't want to use Managed Metadata fields, I think that your approach is good, but instead of using timer job/scheduled console application, you can use event receiver. Then all changes would be reflected immediately. Another option would be creating some custom application page/web part to manage choice fields, but this would involve more work.

Comment: but the problem is that our customer is not comfortable with the user experience of using managed metadata fields , and they prefer the more common approach of using drop-down lists,, i know managed metadata will provide a better way to allow end users to add terms,, but they do not want us to use managed metadata fields.. now if there were Managed Metadata with drop-down look and feel it will be what i am looking for...

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Managed Metadata Choice Field suggested by @Paweł Hawrylak .

> Option 2: To use a option in the choice field "Fill-in" choice and set it to Yes. The users will be able to submit their own values plus the option provided already to them .[image]

Comment: but the problem is that our customer is not comfortable with the user experience of using managed metadata fields , and they prefer the more common approach of using drop-down lists,, i know managed metadata will provide a better way to allow end users to add terms,, but they do not want us to use managed metadata fields.. now if there were Managed Metadata with drop-down look and feel it will be what i am looking for...